Looking for WFM advice for Salesforce Voice Cloud
Apologies if this has been asked before, but I'm struggling to find what I'm looking for.  My company is looking to move away from Five9 on Salesforce and we're thinking of using Salesforce Voice Cloud for our contact centre's customer engagement.  We've used Five9 for a while now, and the decision to move away from it is something taken at a higher level than me, but I've been asked to look into the best WFM to use alongside Service Voice Cloud.
Are there any developers out there who've moved onto SVC who can advise what they think would be the best/optimal WFM to use?
What I'm after is some suggestions that I can then do more digging into.  Our Contact Centre is quite large (more than 80 users), so I'm after something that is both robust but also user friendly if possible.  Any info on implementation would also be greatly appreciated - did developers find it particularly hard to set it up, is the vendor's customer service proactive, etc?
Apologies if this is a rather vague question - this is all rather new to me as I mostly just work on updating the current system our users use.  This is the first time I've been involved in updating the system properly, so I'm hoping to pick more experienced user's brains so that I don't mess it up!

You'll have more luck on dedicated sister site, https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/, more admins & consultants lurk there. And if they're associated to a product they're peddling - they have to disclose that. As this is not a specific coding problem it's a poor fit for StackOverflow. And well... "best"... Check with your SF account manager if there's an "accelerator" about SVC you could benefit from. Eyeball some 3rd parties on appexchange, ask for a demo? Trailhead self-paced training? https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.voice_about.htm&type=5

Cheers buddy - I'll take a look at that site you mentioned, and see if I can get any further with it!
